# How will I sort a list using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to sort a list on my site using JavaScript. I've search on w3c but it seems that I need to make a button for that. I want to sort a list automatically. Please help me.

Comment: Use the `.sort()` method, which is part of the array prototype.  Based on what little info you've given, that's the best I can give you.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: thank you I'll read that article and I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.sort(<compare function>)`

*From MDN:*

The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

**Examples**

**For Ascending**

```
    var arr = [1, 6, 3, 8, 10, 3, 4, -1]; //unsorted array
    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });
```

result: `-1,1,3,3,4,6,8,10`

**or**

```
var arr = [1, 6, 3, 8, 10, 3, 4, -1]; //unsorted array
arr.sort(sortAscending);

function sortAscending(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

result: `-1,1,3,3,4,6,8,10`

**For Descending**

```
var arr = [1, 6, 3, 8, 10, 3, 4, -1]; //unsorted array
arr.sort(sortDescending);

function sortDescending(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}
```

result: `10,8,6,4,3,3,1,-1`

**NOTE** The compare function being passed may not suit your needs so you need to be more specific about what you're sorting for an answer that's more specific to your problem